# Combo box Partial match go to Row

Tags: excel

I have a excel file with 2 worksheets, Production and PlantList.  The Production worksheet lists plant varieties by size with their corresponding production numbers. Each variety may have multiple sizes. The Production worksheet is created by taking the production varieties list and removing duplicates then finding the first size listed and then finding the corresponding row.  I currently search with a combobox using the plantlist (3 columns (name, sizes, row)) to find the row then press a button to go to the listed row.

This method insists that the combo box be typed exactly as the PlantList variety is shown. I would like to be able to enter partial information then choose from the options and then go to the correct row when the option is chosen.

Suggestions?

Comment: Try `instr`? Also, please post your code. Edit: if you are just trying to get to a row, why not just do autofilter? It will start filtering as you type.

Comment: The goal is to go to the specific set of rows. Often we search the file to look at and make changes based on other varieties listed nearby. The autofilter shows the column as it is which currently is alphabetical by category. One would have to know which category to look in before selecting. An overall alphabetical list would be better. I'm just missing the partial search option.

Comment: At this point all I have is a combobox calling the Plantlist (which lists plants and row number) and using that to find the row. Then I put that number in a cell and us a button with a macro that says go to row specified in the former cell.